# Where are websites html/js stored on local computer, in chrome, windows 10?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

When typing some url, e.g `www.google.com` (or `www.news.com` or any other), some client-side code gets downloaded to my local machine, so that the browser can display and run whatever is in there.

I would like to look at that code and maybe slightly modify it.

My google searches failed, probably because I am unfamiliar with the correct terminology for what I am searching. I wasn't even sure about which tags to put on this question.

**Where are websites client-side files stored locally? Specifically on chrome, windows 10**

Comment: Wherever the client application decides to store it.

Comment: Each browser maintains its local cache.  Some may not even be as browse-able files on the file system.

Comment: allright, then how can I search for that location, for example on chrome? searching only gives me results related to "local-storage" which is not what I need

Comment: [What problem are you really trying to solve?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Because "digging the file out of the browser cache" is unlikely to be a good solution to it, whatever it is.

Comment: “*I would like to look at that code and maybe slightly modify it*” - Are you looking for the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)?

Comment: @Gulzar: https://superuser.com/questions/1316540/where-has-chrome-cache-been-moved-to

Comment: @Quentin This was the question I wanted to ask. I wanted a tool in my toolbox that allows me to look at the client side code that runs on my machine. This is not problem specific.

Comment: @Gulzar — Then View > Source would be a lot less complicated than trying to find stuff in the cache.

Comment: Search terms are bolded: If you want to view and edit at the source of the page you're currently looking at, and have your changes reflected in the page immediately, use the browser **developer tools** (this will be much better than "View source").  If you want to make changes that would *persist*, i.e. every time you view a particular website your changes will be applied to it automatically, then you're looking at building yourself a **browser extension**.   Browsers don't, as far as I know, store the source of a page during render on disk in any way that can be viewed or usefully modified.

Comment: @DanielBeck I would accept this if it were an answer, this is exactly what I was searching for

Comment: Glad I could help!  I went ahead and expanded that into an answer below.

Comment: Honestly, I have no Idea why this question got so many downvotes. I stand by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view and edit at the source of the page you're currently looking at, and have your changes reflected in the page immediately, use the **[browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)** (this will be much better than "View source", as it will interpret any clientside DOM generation, give you a collapsible, edited, nested-list view of the DOM, etc).

If you want to make changes that would persist, i.e. every time you view a particular website your changes will be applied to it automatically, then you're looking at building yourself a **browser extension**, either for your [specific browser](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) or [cross-browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Build_a_cross_browser_extension).

Browsers don't, as far as I know, store the source of a page during render on disk in any way that can be viewed or usefully modified.